# Connect to an SSH server over an HTTP proxy using plink and netcat

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, netcat, plink

I'm trying to connect to an SSH server from a Windows PC behind a corporate HTTP proxy.

The trick works under Debian using OpenSSH client with `ncat` from the nmap package, but it does not work under Windows with Plink 0.70 + Ncat 7.70 (https://nmap.org). Putty works fine too, though using pure plink would be better for me.

Plink has the `-proxycmd` option, which seems to be similar to the `ProxyCommand` option in OpenSSH. However, it does not work as expected (SSH server is running on port 443):

```
plink.exe -C -ssh -P 443 -i my_pvt_key.ppk -proxycmd "ncat --verbose --proxy-type http --proxy 192.168.101.200:3128 %host %port" -sshlog sshlog.txt root@192.0.2.123
```

The command immediately returns "FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection".

Putty log:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2018.07.19 07:38:28 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: sshlog.txt
Event Log: Starting local proxy command: ncat --verbose --proxy-type http --proxy 192.168.101.200:3128 port
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
Event Log: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

The third line of the log is confusing. There is the word 'port' in the end of the command, and it should have been replaced with the actual port. Host `192.0.2.123` is not shown at all.

The command `ncat --verbose --proxy-type http --proxy 192.168.101.200:3128 192.0.2.123 443` itself seems to work fine. Thus, I suppose, the problem is that Plink doesn't parse arguments in the ncat command correctly. I am probably wrong.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

In Putty, in Configuration->Connection->Proxy, you can configure a HTTP Proxy directly without using `ncat`.

In `plink`, you can refer to a Putty configuration. The help text says

> "host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name

So just call `plink` with the configuration you saved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you question, i success in Window 10 1903 via open ssh, below is my command:

```
 ssh root@domain.com -o "ProxyCommand C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\ncat.exe --verbose --proxy-type http --proxy 127.0.0.1:10801 %h %p" -v
```

With plink: Release 0.71(64-bit), OP command work fine, but cmd will show some not recognized chart without color. Better to use open ssh in windows 10?

```
plink.exe -C -ssh -P 27158 -i C:\Users\xxx\.ssh\test.ppk -proxycmd "ncat --verbose --proxy-type http --proxy 127.0.0.1:10801 %host %port" root@xxx.xxx-sshlog sshlog.txt
```

Comment: The question is not about using SSH as the client.